# How do change the contents of a webpage by using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I want to change a (Classic-ASP) webpage by using JavaScript. Sorry I must...

The page is as like this:

```
<input maxlength='30' id='InputX1' type='text' ...>&nbsp;

<table class='CustomSelectTable' id='CustomTableY' ...>
    <tr>
        <td style='height: 20px;'>
            <input type='text' class='clsComboboxWithBorder required' id='InputX2' ...>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Really they are two variables like this:

```
sInputVal = "<input maxlength..."
sTalbeVal = "<table class..."
```

and I want to change it like this:

```
<table class='CustomSelectTable' id='CustomTableY' ...>
    <tr>
        <td style='height: 20px;'>
            <input maxlength='30' id='InputX1' type='text' ...>&nbsp;
            <input type='text' class='clsComboboxWithBorder required' id='InputX2' ...>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Which code do you need and do you do that?

Comment: Strange you need to do this, do you not have access to the source code?

Comment: I can't change the source too much... The solution has to be sContents = sContents & fnAddControl(sTableVal, sInputVal) & vbCrLf. And I want to create a function fnAddControl.

Comment: In that case edit your question and post your the relevant part of your ASP page source so I can advise you better. I'm still struggling with what it is you are actually trying to do.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With jQuery it would be:

```
$('#InputX2').parent().prepend($('#InputX1'));
```